# Fastest way to check whether the cursor returned by a template helper is empty?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I often do something like this, using the `items` helper twice:

```
{{#if items}}
<h1>Items</h1>
  {{#each items}}
    {{> item}}
  {{/each}}
{{/if}}

Template.foo.helpers
  items: ->
    Items.find 
      bar: true
    , 
      sort: created: -1
      transform: (item) ->
        i.good = true
        i
```

Is Meteor doing extra work in this scenario? Would it be more efficient to switch the `if` to use something like `areItems`?

```
areItems: ->
  Items.find
    bar: true
  .count() > 0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the template, you can use {{#with items}} and then either 'this.count' or 'this.length' to check whether your helper returned any items.

Use this.count if 'items' is a cursor, e.g. the result of a find() operation:

```
{{#with items}}
  {{#if this.count}}
    <h1>Items</h1>
    {{#each this}}
      {{> item}}
    {{/each}}
  {{/if}}
{{/with}}
```

Use this.length if 'items' is an array:

```
{{#with items}}
  {{#if this.length}}
    <h1>Items</h1>
    {{#each this}}
      {{> item}}
    {{/each}}
  {{/if}}
{{/with}}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use `{{else}}`

```
{{#each this}}
   {{> item}}
{{else}}
   <h1>No Items</h1>   
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want anything displayed when there are no items.

Comment: @Loren sorry I misunderstood you. You can use `{{#if this.count))` for the h1 title

Comment: I couldn't get `#each this` to work when `this` was a cursor, but could when I added `.fetch()` to the end of the helper. And then I used `#if this.length`.

Comment: This is great and much simpler than the accepted answer and if you don't want anything displayed simply delete the `<h1>No Items</h1>` line and it won't display... although I think this is the default behaviour anyway if there are no items.

Answer (score 1):

Use `#with`, `#if this.length`, and `.fetch`:

```
{{#with items}}
  {{#if this.length}}
  <h1>Items</h1>
    {{#each this}}
      {{> item}}
    {{/each}}
  {{/if}}
{{/with}}

Template.foo.helpers
  items: ->
    Items.find 
      bar: true
    , 
      sort: created: -1
      transform: (item) ->
        i.good = true
        i
    .fetch()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want using spacebars' `#with` block tag.

Like this:

```
{{#with items}}
  {{#if this.count}}<h1>Items</h1>{{/if}}
  {{#each this}}
    {{> item}}
  {{/each}}
{{/with}}
```

The block tag is [documented here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md#with).  The relevant quote is:

> If the argument to #with is falsy (by the same rules as for #if), the content is not rendered.

---

update: fixed code for desired behaviour.  Also while my example demonstrates making one helper call it is better practice to make an 'itemList' template and include it by using {{> itemList items}}.

Comment: I tried that, but when there are no items, the <h1> is being displayed. I guess a cursor with no data isn't falsy?

Comment: @Loren, yeah, I think you need to wrap everything in the `#with` block in an `#if` block, and use `count` as the condition.

Comment: So just to be clear, you are saying your original code does not work?  Or is there a bug with #with where it does not operate the same as #if as documented?

Comment: My original code does work, I am just concerned that I'm making meteor do more work than is needed by calling the helper twice. Got it to work using #with – see comment to other answer.

Comment: I just tested {{#if items}} in a demo on meteorpad and as expected it behaves exactly like {{#with items}}.  The h1 text is displayed for an empty cursor.  This makes your question a bit of a mess.  I will update my code with a second #if so it works as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I found that simply `{{#if items.count}}` was sufficient.

```
{{#if items.count}}
  <h2>Below there are items</h2>
{{/if}}

{{#each items}}
  <div class="item-name">{{this.name}}</div>
{{else}}
  <h2>There are no items</h2>
{{else}}
```