# Populating template through router in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, iron-router

I have a Meteor app. I have created a collection `Messages`.

I am publishing the messages on the server with

```
Meteor.publish("messages", function () {
  return Messages.find({'isDeleted': {$ne : true}}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
});
```

I am routing with `iron-router`:

```
this.route('messages', {
  path: '/messages',
  template: 'messages',
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('messages');
  },
  data: function() {
    return Messages.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
  }
});
```

With this function, I use `data: ...` but I still need to use a helper in `messages.js` to actually get the data:

```
Template.messages.helpers({
  messages: function() {
    return Messages.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
  },
});
```

Now I am ready to use the messages in the template with

```
{{#each messages}}
  {{> message}}
{{/each}}
```

Am I doing it correct or could I avoid using the helper and just let the router populate the template with the data? It seems to me that what I do is quite redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether or not you should use `data` from your router is a matter of taste. Let's assume you decide to use it...

1. You can remove your helper. You are correct - it's redundant.
2. The data context for your template is `this` so you can change your template code to:

```html
{{#each this}}
  {{> message}}
{{/each}}
```

---

Alternatively, if you'd like to avoid using `this` in your template, just modify your `data` as follows:

```js
data: function() {
  return {messages: Messages.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}})};
}
```

And now you can keep your original template code:

```
{{#each messages}}
  {{> message}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thank you! I am very new to Meteor. Is it good practice to use data in the router and would you recommend using `this`?

Comment: What if I want to check if `messages` is empty before I print them? I have found that I can use `{{#if items.length}}` but it seems not to work with `{{# if this.length}}`?

Comment: Honestly, I'm still torn on the issue and have been for some time. We use `data` in our router code but it feels a bit funny to me that the router should decide the context of the template. If you do use it, I personally like my 2nd suggestion to avoid using `this` in the template. Technically there's nothing wrong with using `this` but it isn't very descriptive.

Comment: For your 2nd question, the `each` should take care of it for you. Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27762610/fastest-way-to-check-whether-the-cursor-returned-by-a-template-helper-is-empty).